# Spreading for object as function input arguments

Tags: javascript

I want to pass in "he", and "she" to function `func` and output "heshe".

Is there any way to spread the value of object (like array) to make it work?

```
  const func=(a,b)=>(a+b);

  const arr=["he","she"];
  console.log(func(...arr));//working

  const obj1={a:"he", "b":"she"}
  console.log(func(...obj1));//not working
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

In your example:

```js
const func=(a,b)=>(a+b);

const obj1={a:"he", "b":"she"}
console.log(func(...Object.values(obj1)));
```